# Send duplicate packets over two Internet connections

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ip

I need to duplicate an RTP stream over two different (non-reliable) Internet connections.

On the receiver side, I will probably run a custom program that will use a buffer and rebuild the stream before using it.

But I have some trouble in splitting the traffic over the two connections. I did some research and found that maybe `tc` (part of `iproute2`) could be what I need.

Comment: @Gilles seems like the way to go, your comment should be an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: See also [Copying packets from an interface to another](http://serverfault.com/questions/225178/copying-packets-from-an-interface-to-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux kernel version 2.6.35 introduces a new configuration option `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TEE`:

> This option adds a "TEE" target with which a packet can be cloned and
>   this clone be rerouted to another nexthop.

[Iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/) supports the `-j TEE` target since 1.4.8.

Earlier support was through the [xtables addons](http://xtables-addons.sourceforge.net/), which include both kernel modules and userland tools. You may still prefer this option if you prefer to stick with your distribution's kernel and it's too old to have `TEE`.

There's a [tutorial by bjou](http://web.archive.org/web/20130723032011/http://www.bjou.de/blog/2008/05/howto-copyteeclone-network-traffic-using-iptables/) (written before the feature was included in the official kernel and iptables).

Comment: Webpage with tutorial requires password :(

Answer (score 0):

The network protocol stack is designed to limit duplication.

You may be better off tunneling over TCP.  Otherwise you will likely need to build your own program to duplicate your output.  How unreliable are your connections.  Mine are usually well over 99.9% reliable.

Comment: It is a mobility scenario: a mobile user uses two different network providers, so that the same data goes to the receiver in the event that one (or the other) has no signal. I'd avoid TCP if possible. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrea:  I would configure the mobile users system to connect using whichever connection is up.  This would eliminate the duplication issue.

Comment: I need to do evaluation of different strategies, duplication is just one of them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a packet sniffing package such as [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) can help you. I recently used it to intercept packets and modify their headers. It essentially amounts to creating a new program as BillThor suggested, but I found scapy very easy to use. While this may not be the best package of its kind, maybe something similar will suit your needs.