# Traffic Forwarding To Server With iptables

Tags: iptables, forwarding, mirror

I have a server `(10.10.0.100)` on the same subnet `(10.10.0.0/24)` with all the rest of the hosts. I would like that server to received a full copy of all traffic (Windows and Linux machines) on it's eth0 interface. I have iptables running on the firewall and that's where I would like to set up the traffic mirroring.

I tried this which didn't work. All traffic went to the server but this way it was forwarded and not copied, hence the hosts no longer were able to go online.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.0.100`

Comment: This is the correct behaviour for what you did. What you want to do instead is to copy the traffic stream, have one copy sent to the legitimate destinations, another copy sent to the host where you want to mirror traffic to. To mirror with iptables you need to use the ROUTE table and the TEE target: have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/853077/iptables-duplicate-traffic-to-another-ip and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15870/iptables-port-mirroring

Comment: @A.B The server a security onion. I would like to analyze network traffic. I know SecurityOnion by default can sniff network traffic if you setup a port mirroring on your switch but this is a virtual environment. I do not have a virtual switch or nothing like that so I have to "force" a copy of the network traffic to the server's interface.

Comment: @Pedro thank you for those rousources. One of them showed this solution:
```iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.15 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.100

 iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.15 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.100```
This^^ didn't work for me. The server received a copy of all traffic but once again the host couldn't go online. 


The other one was talking about forwarding specific ports. Either I misunderstood something (very possible) or this is not applicable for me.

Comment: @Pedro actually these rules seem to have done the trick. I am testing it now. I had to restart the firewall for some reason and now it works. 

```iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.15 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.100 

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.15 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.100```

Comment: OK, I'll copy the comment into an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(copied from my comment) This is the correct behaviour for what you did - redirecting traffic.

However, what you want to do instead is to copy the traffic stream, have one copy sent to the legitimate destinations, another copy sent to the host where you want to mirror traffic to.

To mirror with iptables you need to use the ROUTE table and the TEE target. Have a look at

- [iptables port-mirroring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15870/iptables-port-mirroring)
- https://superuser.com/questions/853077/iptables-duplicate-traffic-to-another-ip

(from a comment by the OP) This combo was tested and verified working by the OP:

`iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.15 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.100`

`iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.15 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.100`