# Port Mirroring in Fedora?

Tags: networking, fedora, iptables, tcp

I have set up an application that listens constantly to a port for network packets, and I would like to create another one that receives the same network packets ( for use as a test bed).  Getting the packets sent to 2 different ports on the machine is not an option, so I was wondering if there is a way to set up a "port-mirror".  Basically, is there an easy way to make all traffic received on port XXXXX also copy to port XXXXX + 1?

I know there is a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15870/iptables-port-mirroring), but I don't quite understand the suggested solution.

Barring that, is there another easy way to simulate network data to test some code with that I am overlooking?

Comment: Have you read [Send duplicate packets over two Internet connections](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10440) and [Copying packets from an interface to another](http://serverfault.com/q/225178) ? It won't get easier than typing a few `iptables` commands. What is your kernel version?

Comment: According to `uname -rs`, I'm on 2.6.32.

Comment: Ok then, have you tried the xtables addon? If you have and ran into problems, tell us how far you got, copy-paste your configuration files and the commands you ran and any error message you got.

Comment: http://www.fclose.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/ your are looking for port forwarding and not mirroring. I bet your question has dozens of duplicate on unix SO and power user

Comment: have a look at openvswitch running a TAP http://openvswitch.org/ . http://openvswitch.org/pipermail/discuss/2012-July/007730.html

Comment: Have you considered port sniffing? And later maybe tcpreplay? It would not be real-time mirroring though.

Answer (score -1):

You might take a look at nc(1), a network swiss army knife of sorts.

Comment: How would you manage to get `nc` duplicate packets?

Comment: It wouldn't. This answer is a red herring.